# How can I send "pong" message when I received ping message from binance with websocketsharp?

Tags: websocket, binance

I lost the connection of user data stream in random time. I think that it happens because I don't send any "pong" messages to binance server. Binance says "The websocket server will send a ping frame every 3 minutes. If the websocket server does not receive a pong frame back from the connection within a 10 minute period, the connection will be disconnected. Unsolicited pong frames are allowed". I tried it by re-sending the ping message to the server but it didn't work. How can I send "pong" message with WebsocketSharp lib?

```
private void OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsPing)
    {
        _websocket.Send(e.RawData);
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The Ping frame contains an opcode of 0x9.

The Pong frame contains an opcode of 0xA.
Before sending back the received data change the opcode from 0x9 to 0xA.
Read more  in the RFC6455.

Comment: I'm not C# guy but after a quick look at this lib. I guess you need to create a `WebSocketFrame` instance with `fin=Fin.FINAL, opcode=Opcode.PONG`, then send this frame back.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocketFrame is internal class, so you can't instance of it. In the last version of the library, there is internal method WebSocketFrame.CreatePongFrame(). As I understood, it sends pong automatically when get ping.